# How can I kill the current php artisan serve session before starting a new one?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, port, laravel-artisan

I often find myself open up so many ports when running `php artisan serve`

```
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
[Thu Dec  2 19:56:23 2021] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8000 (reason: Address already in use)
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8001>
[Thu Dec  2 19:56:23 2021] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8001 (reason: Address already in use)
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8002>
[Thu Dec  2 19:56:23 2021] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:8002 (reason: Address already in use)
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8003>
```

Is there away to kill http://127.0.0.1:8000 before starting a new one ?

so my application will be at http://127.0.0.1:8000...

Any hint for on how to do that ?

Comment: How did you try to solve your problem? Can you share what you attempted or what errors you got?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can **close the terminal**, and then the port automatically gets killed.

But if that does not work, you can kill the process manually by running this command :

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:8000)
```

Comment: I want to programmatically end the current one before I start a new one

Comment: Yes `kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8000) ; php artisan serve`. Is this not programmatical?

Comment: Sometimes, I got error : `kill:1: not enough arguments`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, Select the terminal from which you ran *php artisan serve* and press Ctrl+c to kill it. Then run php artisan serve again.